# Git ignoring files it should not

Tags: git, android-studio

I recently noticed most of my core files, including MainActivity.java were being ignored by Git. I could not stop Git from ignoring them by right-clicking and then clicking on Git->Add, as subsequently doing a commit would produce a "No changes detected" message. The files were not listed in the most conspicuous .gitignore file, but after some digging I found a second .gitignore where my core files were indeed listed and I solved the problem (apparently) by manually erasing them from this file. Thinking back, I believe the core files (as well as some other apparently random files) were added to .gitignore when I answered "Yes" to a dialog that asked whether "unversioned files" should be ignored. This seems rather arbitrary and treacherous because other files in the same directories, with no apparent rhyme or reason, were not "unversioned" and therefore not added to gitignore.

My questions are:

1) What could cause some files to be "unversioned" while other files, including newer files in the same directory, were not?

2) Is there a more proper way to get Git to stop ignoring files than to manually erase them from .gitignore?

Comment: Files should not be ignored by default. They are _untracked_ by default. Your .gitignore file should not contain `.java` files, bu only `.class` files and the like. See [This github](https://github.com/github/gitignore) for inspiration or outright theft :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand the questions correctly but I think one of them is: **how can I get git to start tracking a file that is being ignored without messing with the .gitignore files set up?** If the question is right, then that is easy to do with the -f option: `git add -f <file-path>`.

About the other question, you should take a look at [update-index](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index) because it can create a nice set of unexpected behaviors in terms of git *not noticing changes*.